# can't find the type 'bigint' in Sybase ASE 12.5.4

Tags: sqldatatypes, sap-ase

is bigint supported in Sybase ASE 12.5.4 ?

if not is there any equalent to bigint in Sybase ASE 12.5.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Bigint was not [added until Sybase ASE 15](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc34982_1500/html/mig_gde/mig_gde113.htm).  The closest to this you will get is [`NUMERIC(19,0)`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc36271_36272_36273_36274_1250/html/refman/X39635.htm) which will provide the same range as bigint but may take up more space.